# Solve absolute equality with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

i want to solve Abs(x - 3) + Abs(x - 4) == 9,
but python returns me an empty list. 
[]

im trying:

sym.solve(sym.Abs(x - 3) + sym.Abs(x - 4) == 0)

where am i wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `==` sign does not do what you want here:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs

Also you'll need to declare `x` as real for this example.

```
In [3]: x = Symbol('x', real=True)

In [4]: solve(Eq(Abs(x-3)+Abs(x-4), 9), x)
Out[4]: [-1, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please provide a full example.

I do not seem to have any problems... What exactly did you try?

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import x, y
sym.solve(sym.Abs(x - 3) + sym.Abs(x - 4) == 0)
```